# Accessing an Application from a Web Browser for Android and iOS

Tags: ios, flash, browser

First and foremost, I am not the developer behind this application, however I am looking for a solution to this problem as I work at the company that runs the application and I've been tasked to do so. This is not a focused code-line question, but more so an application question.

**Background**: The application is an educational tool that simulates a physical science laboratory that is programmed using *Flash*. It is accessed from a Learning Management System (LMS) web browser - i.e. Blackboard, Canvas, etc. - through a link to the object. There are *multiple* simulated labs that are each their own object.

**The main problem**: The simulators/labs are able to be accessed on an Android device (phones & tablets) by prompting a download of a .apk file once the link is clicked on that device where they will have a menu that localizes all the simulators. This is to centralize all the simulators into one menu app. Now, when you attempt this process on an iOS device, it's obviously incompatible (.apk vs .ipa). We can create a runnable .ipa file for each individual simulator, but this is not efficient at all when attempting to execute on a mass scale (think district-wide access).

*What I want to find out is the most efficient way to adapt the application for iOS since it utilizes Flash*. The same process would be desired (click the link and it prompts a download of the menu app that holds the sims/labs).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enrol for apple developer program to distribute builds. Normal subscription consider distribution thought App Store, and it seems not your case. There is Enterprise subscription - it allows to create .ipa, that can be installed on any device, but distributed locally (Ad-Hoc). While assembling Ad-Hoc build in latest Xcode you can select opportunity to create distribution manifest as well (Xcode will provide description how to use it). Then you can upload manifest and iPad file to you file server, and share link to manifest with you user. Opening manifest on iDevice will launch installation of application.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you saying that the simulators will have to be re-programmed in Swift/Objective C in order to have functionality on iOS? Because again, the program uses Flash too. As well, we are a business that sells the software/application to schools.

Comment: Natively iOS don't support Flash. So you definitely need some app to run it. There is few apps that can run flash on iOS, like Puffin Browser https://itunes.apple.com/ae/app/puffin-web-browser/id472937654?mt=8, but It if you need descent solution, perhaps you need to create app designated to run your flash code, and distribute make it available through Enterprise distribution, or AppStore. Definitely it depends on what you have, but there is a lot of apps that is wrapper/container with web view in it running HTML/JS. Perhaps you need something like this.